# Как добавить данные в функцию кнопки

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть цикл:

```js
    <?php for ($id = 0; $id < $style['count']; $id++):?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="text-center id-style">
                 <?php echo $style['arraystyle'][$id]['id'];?>
            </th>
            <td><input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $style['arraystyle'][$id]['name'];?>" type="text"></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="styleEdit()">Изменить</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php endfor;?>
```

Как мне в функцию **styleEdit()** передать данные из **th** и **td** что бы дальше проводить манипуляции?

Comment: `onclick="styleEdit('<?=json_encode($style['arraystyle'][$id]);?>')" ... function styleEdit(style) { let styles = JSON.parse(style); ...}`

Comment: это я передам th, а мне как мне еще передать значение td которое ввожу в инпут?

Comment: что мешает с него получить нужное значение?

Comment: а как кнопка поймет что именно с этого инпута нужно брать значение?

Comment: определитесь, нужно вам значение с инпута или данные, которые в инпут подставляются